# Get HTML output in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, output

```
<html>
<form action="TEMP.php" method="POST">

<output name="Total"> 0.00 </output>

</form>
</html>




<?php 
$Output=$_POST['Total'];
?>
```

How do i get the HTML output as php variable? This is not working for output. There is an example in this link, the output will auto show the amount at beside. But now i need to get it as variable in PHP.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

Answer (score 0):

`<output>` isn't a valid form tag inside a form. The `name` attribute is correct, but the tag must be `<input>`

```
    <html>
    <form action="TEMP.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="Total" value="0.00">0.00</output>

    </form>
    </html>




<?php 
    $Output=$_POST['Total'];
    echo "The value for total was: " . $Output;
?>
```

Comment: No, i got other bunch of code in HTML, i just simplify it. The output is correct and nothing wrong with it. Now i just need to get the output value in PHP.

Comment: i know we cant submit the output value to php, but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @JtTan Maybe I misunderstood the question. Which output are you talking about? The variable or the server output? Are you trying to get PHP to get the data '0.00' or something else?